# django - query and delete GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-contenttypes

Suppose, this is a model as the foreignkey for `ContentType`:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

And this is a model for `ContentType`:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type','object_id')
```

Whenever a new photo or a status is created, a new `Entry` is also created. Now, what I want is that, whenever I delete an instance of `Photo`/`Status`, I want to delete the object from `Entry` which is related to that photo/status? How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
def delete_entry(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    try:
        si = Entry.objects.get(object_id=instance.id)
        si.delete()
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        si = None
```

Sometimes its working. But again sometimes I get an error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned
get() returned more than one Entry -- it returned 2!
```

So, I guess, thats not the way to do it. Please help me how to solve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there can in fact be duplicate ids in the `GenericForeignKey`. E.g. if you have a `Photo` model and an `Article` model, both with an `Entry` associated with it, the photo's primary key can be the same value as the article's primary key, and the `object_id`s will be the same. That's why you need both a `content_type` and an `object_id` to begin with.

To get the right object, you need to check for both the type and id.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

def delete_entry(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
    entry = Entry.objects.get(content_type=content_type, 
                              object_id=instance.id)
    entry.delete()
```

Another way to accomplish this is to use a `GenericRelation` (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations)). This is the reverse relation of a `GenericForeignKey`. Whenever an object with a `GenericRelation` is deleted, this cascades to any objects of the supplied model with a `GenericForeignKey` pointing to that instance:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericRelation

class Photo(models.Model):
    ...
    entries = GenericRelation(Entry, content_type_field='content_type', 
                              object_id_field='object_id')
```

Comment: I don't see that the approach with GenericRelation is working. Instead, after delete, I have still the Entry instance with the earlier .object_id. And .content_object is None. Why the Entry instance is not deleted? What I do wrong?

Comment: So I know the reason in my case. I work on some company code. GenericRelation attributes were added not inside the model, but en bloc using .ready() method in apps.py. And this is our bug, because it is to late there. Back links work fine (probably they are handled in django using lazy definition), but the cascade deleting silently fails.